# Can you move a firebase hosting site to a different project?

Tags: firebase, hosting, firebase-hosting

So, I was wondering, is it possible to move a firebase hosting site to a different project?.

I searched through the documentation, but I dont see anything anywhere that says how to do it, or if it is even possible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in operation to move to a new project. But if you're deploying with the Firebase CLI, you can run:

```
firebase use <new project ID>
```

And then:

```
firebase deploy
```

To deploy the same content to the other project.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your code for the site then you can just create a new folder and use `firebase init hosting` and initialize hosting in new project.
After that the process of deploying remains the same i.e.

```
firebase deploy --only hosting
```

PS: Also if you are using any custom domains, you would have to verify the ownership of the domain again in the new project.